# Warning : rand() expects parameter to be long

Tags: php

Getting the following error:

> Warning: rand() expects parameter 2 to be long, array given in
>   C:\wamp\www\honeydev\python.php on line 61

Following is the code:

```
58 $max_passno=$dbo->prepare("select count(*) from user_password"); //find the max. no of entries in user_password table
59 $max_passno->execute();
60 $row = $max_passno->fetch();
61 $no2 = rand(1, $row); //select a random number
```

Can someone suggest, what changes are required to resolve this please?

Comment: `$row` is an array, not a number. The the element in the array, not the array itself.

Comment: `$count = $max_passno->fetchColumn(); $no2 = rand(1, $count);`

Comment: Thank you @Jack !!! You should have posted that in Answer!

Answer (score 4):

Read the error message again. It states, quite clearly, what the problem is and where it is.

`rand(1, 999);`

Parameter 2 needs to be a number. For some awesome reason, you threw an array in there. Pretty fun, but it won't work that way.

```
$max_passno=$dbo->prepare("select count(*) as count from user_password"); //find the max. no of entries in user_password table
$max_passno->execute();
$row = $max_passno->fetch();
$no2 = rand(1, $row['count']); //select a random number
```

For future reference, it may help to examine the variable in question.

`var_dump($row);`